# How to build an ASP.NET Proxy Site

Tags: asp.net, proxy

I want to build a proxy site that renders any URL.

Given an url, I need to replace all html links, css links and js urls from

href="/original.htm"

to

href="http://www.myproxy.com/get?www.original.com/original.htm"

sort of.

How can I do? is there a ready-to-use framework? I use ASP.NET and C#.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/asproxy.aspx